# Prime Ideal of a Localization

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ a ring, $p, q$ prime ideals of $R$ and $R_p$ localisation of $R$ under $p$.

Is that always true that $q R_p$ is a prime ideal in $R_p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $p=2\mathbb{Z}, q=3\mathbb{Z}$, $qR_p=R_p$ here.

Answer (score 2):

See Atiyah-Macdonald, proposition 3.11
It is well-known that  if $q\subseteq p$, then $q R_p$ is a prime ideal in $R_p$.

---

But if $q\nsubseteq p$, then $q R_p= R_p$:

Let $s\in q\setminus p$. then $\dfrac 11=\dfrac ss \in q R_p$

Comment: Tsemo's example has the property $q\nsubseteq p$.